# How to Convert RX.Observable to IO.reactivex.Observable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am querying database using rxjava jdbc library but using rx1 supported library.

`rx.Observable<T> rx1 =Database.from(url, user,password).autoMap(resultType);`

I am trying to convert this to

`io.reactivex.Observable.fromIterable(BlockingObservable.from(rx1).toIterable());`

but it is not working can i get the equivalent code for RX Java 2 . I mean i wanted to return back `io.reactivex.Observable<T>`  instead of `rx.Observable<T>`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`RxJavaInterop`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaInterop/tree/v0.13.7) library to convert between RxJava1 and RxJava2 types. It provides functions to convert between all the different reactive types supported by both versions. In your case, you can convert your RxJava1 `Observable` to an RxJava2 `Observable` like this:

```java
io.reactivex.Observable<T> rx2 = RxJavaInterop.toV2Observable(rx1);
```

The library is maintained by the lead developer from the RxJava project itself, so you can be confident it's reliable. Just be sure to use a version of the library from the v0.x branch - more recent versions (3.x) are for converting between RxJava1 and RxJava3.

Comment: thank you for your input, I tried and  it has solved the problem. In the meanwhile i had also tried upgrading rxjava2 jdbc driver that automatically return RX2 Observable but i could not use that one as quick solution to this problem as the API has changed .